# Pandas Modify Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
           0         1      2         3         4         5
    0  0.428519  0.000000  0.0  0.541096  0.250099  0.345604
    1  0.056650  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    2  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    3  0.849066  0.559117  0.0  0.374447  0.424247  0.586254
    4  0.317644  0.000000  0.0  0.271171  0.586686  0.424560
```

I would like to modify it as below

```
    0      0     0.428519
    0      1     0.000000
    0      2     0.0
    0      3     0.541096
    0      4     0.250099
    0      5     0.345604
    1      0     0.056650
    1      1     0.000000
    ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
```

```
print (df1)
    col1 col2      col3
0      0    0  0.428519
1      0    1  0.000000
2      0    2  0.000000
3      0    3  0.541096
4      0    4  0.250099
5      0    5  0.345604
6      1    0  0.056650
7      1    1  0.000000
8      1    2  0.000000
9      1    3  0.000000
10     1    4  0.000000
11     1    5  0.000000
12     2    0  0.000000
13     2    1  0.000000
14     2    2  0.000000
15     2    3  0.000000
16     2    4  0.000000
17     2    5  0.000000
18     3    0  0.849066
19     3    1  0.559117
20     3    2  0.000000
21     3    3  0.374447
22     3    4  0.424247
23     3    5  0.586254
24     4    0  0.317644
25     4    1  0.000000
26     4    2  0.000000
27     4    3  0.271171
28     4    4  0.586686
29     4    5  0.424560
```

Numpy solution with [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), flattening is by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns)),
        "col2": np.tile(df.columns, len(df.index)),
        "col3": df.values.ravel()})
```

```
print (df2) 
    col1 col2      col3
0      0    0  0.428519
1      0    1  0.000000
2      0    2  0.000000
3      0    3  0.541096
4      0    4  0.250099
5      0    5  0.345604
6      1    0  0.056650
7      1    1  0.000000
8      1    2  0.000000
9      1    3  0.000000
10     1    4  0.000000
11     1    5  0.000000
12     2    0  0.000000
13     2    1  0.000000
14     2    2  0.000000
15     2    3  0.000000
16     2    4  0.000000
17     2    5  0.000000
18     3    0  0.849066
19     3    1  0.559117
20     3    2  0.000000
21     3    3  0.374447
22     3    4  0.424247
23     3    5  0.586254
24     4    0  0.317644
25     4    1  0.000000
26     4    2  0.000000
27     4    3  0.271171
28     4    4  0.586686
29     4    5  0.424560
```